# What is the ' world to come' as referred to in Mtt 12:32?

Tags: soteriology, matt

We read in Mtt  12:32(KJV):

> And whosoever speaketh a word against the Son of man, it shall be forgiven him: but whosoever speaketh against the Holy Ghost, it shall not be forgiven him, neither in this world, neither in the world to come.

That implies that there are certain sins that could be forgiven in  the world to come. Christianity, irrespective of denominations,  believes in eternal salvation and eternal damnation as mutually exclusive outcomes of one's life on earth. Some denomination like Catholicism believe in the existence of Purgatory where sins not absolved during one's life are made up for. But, a person who dies unrepentant in grave sin invites eternal condemnation. No doubt, one commits a grave sin by speaking against the Holy Spirit. So, what is the ' world to come' as referred to by Jesus in Mtt 12:32 ?

Answer (score 1):

The world to come is **The new heaven and the new earth**. God will destroy this **world** and in doing so he has to **create a new world without sin and corruption**.
John saw a vision of this new world while he was in the island of Patmos through an angel

**Revelation 21:1-2**

> Then I saw “a new heaven and a new earth,”[a] for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea.

Jesus implies that blasphemy against The Holy Spirit is a sin that makes someone guilty of eternal damnation.

Comment: The word is _aion_ (age) not _kosmos_ ('world'). But I have up-voted as your concept is correct, despite that detail being not quite accurate. The emphasis is upon _duration_ not substance.

Comment: @NigelJ, Thanks , the new age will be ushered in by a new world.

Comment: It is the return of Christ which is crucial and that is dependent on the will of the Father for even the Son of man knoweth not the day nor the hour.

Comment: @NigelJ, very true. After Christ establishes his millennial rule here on earth then the new age will be in effect. Do you mind if I invite you to a private Google chat bar via your email address?

Comment: I don't go with the 'millenial rule' as you call it. The coming of the Lord signals the end of time and the beginning of an endless age. I am thoroughly against the idea of an earthly kingdom being set up after the Son of man returns. The parables of Jesus are thoroughly against any such concept. You may email me, II have no idea what a 'Google chat' is. My email address is on my profile.

Comment: @NigelJ, Thanks. I will show you the verse that supports that Jesus lifts the saints and rules the nations with an iron fist

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "world/age to come" occurs a number of times in the NT and always refers to the world that will exist after the final judgement and great resurrection of the dead.  See appendix below.

Thus, the "age/world" to come was the time when the righteous receive eternal life and the wicked receive eternal damnation.  Essentially, Jesus is saying that blasphemy against the Holy Spirit incurs eternal damnation as such people cannot be forgiven.

**APPENDIX - "World/age to Come"**

The phrase "world to come" (or similar) occurs in the following places:

- Matt 12:32 - And if anyone speaks a word against the Son of Man, it will be forgiven him; but if anyone speaks against the Holy Spirit, it will not be forgiven him, neither in this age nor in the **coming one**.
- Mark 10:30 - who shall not receive a hundredfold now in this time--houses and brothers and sisters and mothers and children and lands, with persecutions--and in the **age which is coming**, eternal life.
- Luke 18:30 - who shall not receive manifold more in this time--and in **the age that is coming**, eternal life."
- Eph 1:21 - above every principality and authority and power and dominion, and every name being named, not only in this age, but also **in the one coming**.
- Eph 2:7 - in order that in the **coming ages** He might show the surpassing riches of His grace in kindness toward us in Christ Jesus.
- 1 Tim 4:8 - For bodily exercise is of a little profit, but godliness is profitable for everything, holding the promise of the present life and of **the one coming**.
- Heb 2:5 - For not to angels did He subject **the world that is coming**, of which we are speaking,
- Heb 6:5 - and having tasted the goodness of God's word and the power of the **coming age**

Comment: Thanks, Dottard, for the resourceful inputs. The focus of my question is the 'world'  where some sins are forgiven and some others ( including blasphemy against the Holy Spirit) are not.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan - that is the point - it is Hebrew idiom for not being forgiven and thus carrying an unforgiven sin into the next life.

Comment: Thanks, Dottard. Am I right in presuming that there are ' forgiveable sins' say, telling a lie to escape a minor  punishment, that carry forward to the next life ?

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan - see my answer - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/89968/is-it-universally-agreed-by-experts-that-the-unpardonable-sin-either-is-unbelief

Answer (score 0):

To delve into the historical side, Jesus's Jewish listeners, "this age" would have likely referred to the current era, marked by the Law and the Prophets, while **the "age to come" represented the future Messianic era when God's kingdom would be fully established.**

On the other hand, the Christian concept of the "age to come" has undergone evolution over time. Initially, Christians looked forward to the realization of God's kingdom. However, this anticipation has been redefined through the lens of Jesus's life, death, and resurrection. In Christian theology, the distinction between "this age" and the "age to come" is perceived as less distinct, **marking the commencement of God's kingdom with Jesus's ministry and continuing through the work of the Holy Spirit in the Church.**

[Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/matthew/12.htm)

> **Neither in this world, neither in the world to come.**—The distinction
> was hardly the same for our Lord’s Jewish listeners as it has come to
> be with us. For them “this world”—better, perhaps, this age—was the
> time before the coming of the Christ; **“the age to come” was that which
> was to follow it. (Comp. Hebrews 6:5, Luke 18:30.)**

[Pulpit Commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/matthew/12.htm)

> **"The age to come" (העולם הבא) included all that followed the coming of
> Messiah.** Sometimes it was restricted to, or practically identified
> with, the reign of Messiah upon earth, but usually it included much
> more - eternity as well as time (see especially Weber, 'System,' pp.
> 354, 355; and cf. Schurer, II. 2:177). It is in its widest sense that
> our Lord here uses it - contrasting the present order of things with
> that which will be the final result of his coming, his thoughts
> travelling far beyond the present course of this world to that which
> is to be hereafter. Matthew 12:32

**Conclusion:** While initially important to the Jewish people as the beginning of a new age, Christianity later blurred the distinction between “this age” and “age to come,” seeing the beginning of God’s kingdom in Jesus’ ministry and the continuing work of the holy spirit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Jewish understanding](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-world-to-come/) of "the world to come," which is most likely how Jesus' hearers would understand it.

> There are two general possibilities: One is that it refers to a
> heavenly abode where the souls of the righteous live on after death.
> The other is that it’s the perfected world that will follow the coming
> of the messiah, when the dead are resurrected and complete peace
> prevails.

It is not clear which sense of the phrase Jesus used in the passage cited in the OP. Even in Jesus' time, the exact meaning of the term would be a matter of opinion. It depends both on whether one thinks it refers to the afterlife or to reign of the messiah on earth.